# Is there a way to get the id of the second-populated drop-down menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am creating an online exam system, and I have two drop-down menus. One menu checks for difficulty level, and based on the selection of "Easy", "Medium", and "Hard", the second menu displays the associated questions. Now, I am trying to retrieve the id of the questions from the second drop-down menu which is based off of the first. I'm pretty new to Ajax, so is there a way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    <form>

    <select id="difficulty" name="difficulty" onchange="changeType();">
    <option value="">Select a difficulty level</option>
    <option value="E" >Easy</option>
    <option value="M">Medium</option>
    <option value="H">Hard</option>
    </select>


    <select name="questions" onchange="showQuestion(this.id)>
    <option id="">Select a question</option>
    <option id="1" onclick="showQuestion(this.id)">Question1</button>
    <option id="2" onclick="showQuestion(this.id)">Question2</button>
    <option id="3"></option>
    <option id="4"></option>
    <option id="5"></option>
    <option id="6"></option>
    </select>


</form>

<script>


    var data =
            [
                {
                    name: "E",
                    options: ["Question1", "Question2"]
                },

                { 
                    name: "M",
                    options: ["Question3", "Question4"]
                },

                {
                    name: "H",
                    options: ["Question5", "Question6"]
                }  
            ];


            function changeType()
            {
                var i, optionSelected, str, j, optionE1Two;

                //get currently selected first option
                optionSelected = document.getElementById("difficulty").value;

                i = 0;
                while (i < data.length && data[i].name != optionSelected)
                {
                    i++;
                }

                //populate second menu
                if(i < data.length)
                {
                    str = '';
                    for(j=0; j<data[i].options.length; j++)
                    {
                        str += '<option value = "'+data[i].options[j]+'">'+data[i].options[j]+'</option>';
                    }

                    optionE1Two = document.getElementById("questions");
                    optionE1Two.innerHTML = str;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("difficulty").addEventListener("change",changeType,false);
</script>


<br>
<div id="text" ><b><center>Questions you select will be listed here.</center></b></div>
<script>
function showQuestion(str) {

    //alert(str); //alert outputs "questions"
   if(str == "") {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else {
        hr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    hr.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    };
    hr.open("GET", "URL", true);
    hr.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Here is my understanding of your logic.

1. User Selects the Difficulty
2. User Selects the Question to work with
3. Then you process that action

You are looking for the ID, value containing the ID, of the selected question? I have put together a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/phatison/pen/boKeEq) of my solution. I tried to avoid making any dramatic changes. I did change:

- Changed 'id' to 'value' on select options
- Modified the 'onChange' event to send the whole element
- Added line 52 to make the questionId a var to make future use a little easier

Using values is preferred for many reasons. One in particular is the accessibility. The DOM allows direct access to the selected index and its value. I do strongly recommend reviewing your code though for syntax errors. There are quite a few. I tackled a few that stuck out and hindered the solution to your question.

P.S. I have made a few more mods as well to fix the changeType() function. It was throwing an error when setting the innerHTML.

```js
var data = [{
    name: "E",
    options: ["Question1", "Question2"]
  },

  {
    name: "M",
    options: ["Question3", "Question4"]
  },

  {
    name: "H",
    options: ["Question5", "Question6"]
  }
];


function changeType() {
  var i, optionSelected, str, j, optionE1Two;

  //get currently selected first option
  optionSelected = document.getElementById("difficulty").value;

  i = 0;
  while (i < data.length && data[i].name != optionSelected) {
    i++;
  }

  //populate second menu
  if (i < data.length) {
    str = '<option value="">Select a question</option>';
    for (j = 0; j < data[i].options.length; j++) {
      str += '<option value = "' + data[i].options[j] + '">' + data[i].options[j] + '</option>';
    }

    optionE1Two = document.getElementById("questions");
    optionE1Two.innerHTML = str;
    
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "<b><center>Questions you select will be listed here.</center></b>";
  }
}
document.getElementById("difficulty").addEventListener("change", changeType, false);

function showQuestion(el) {
  // Accepting the element allows direct access
  console.dir(el.value); // consoles the value of the selected option.

  var questionId = el.value;

  if (questionId == "") {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "<b><center>Questions you select will be listed here.</center></b>";
    return;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "<b><center>You have selected Question: " + el.options[el.selectedIndex].text + "</center></b>";
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    hr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  hr.open("GET", "URL", true);
  hr.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="difficulty" name="difficulty" onchange="changeType();">
    <option value="">Select a difficulty level</option>
    <option value="E" >Easy</option>
    <option value="M">Medium</option>
    <option value="H">Hard</option>
    </select>
  <!-- changed the change event to send the element as a whole -->
  <select name="questions" id="questions" onchange="showQuestion(this)">
      <option value="">Select a question</option>
      <option value="1">Question1</option>
      <option value="2">Question2</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="text">
  <b><center>Questions you select will be listed here.</center></b>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !